How to reset a bot's state in aiogram?
The bot is written in aiogram
I can’t figure out how to make it so that when I start the command, I can restart the code again. To prevent the code from sending user_login and user_password values that are already in it.
I tried through states but it gave an error
bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
dp.middleware.setup(LoggingMiddleware())

user_states = {}

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):

    # dp.message_handlers.clear()

    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    keyboard.add(types.KeyboardButton(text="Да"))
    keyboard.add(types.KeyboardButton(text="Нет"))
    # Запускаем цикл в асинхронной функции

    await message.answer("Привет! Я бот для площадки moodle.")
    await message.answer(f"Твой профиль {response.get_profile(user_login, user_password)}?", reply_markup=keyboard)

@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text in ['Да', 'Нет'])
async def handle_response(message: types.Message):

    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    keyboard.add(types.KeyboardButton(text="СТОП"))

    if message.text == 'Да':
        await message.answer("Хорошо, начинаю работу. Если произойдёт ошибка, то нажми кнопку 'СТОП'.", reply_markup=keyboard)
        # Запускаем цикл в асинхронной функции
        await some_loop(message.chat.id)
    if message.text == 'Нет':
        await message.answer("Ну нет, так нет.", reply_markup=None)
        return


gets = True
@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text in ['СТОП'])
async def stop_res(message: types.Message):
    # keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    # keyboard.add(types.KeyboardButton(text="СТОП"))

    if message.text == "СТОП":
        global gets
        gets = False
        await message.answer("Бот остановлен, нужен перезапуск", reply_markup=None)

    return
    



async def some_loop(chat_id):
    global gets
    counter = 0
    while gets:
        counter += 1
        # Выводим определенные сообщения
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, response.resless())
        await asyncio.sleep(10)  # Ждем 5 секунд перед отправкой следующего сообщения

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)

I tried to solve the problem via chatgpt, but without success.

Have you tried using fsm?
from aiogram.fsm.context import FSMContext

Now you can create class with different states
class sampleClass(StatesGroup):
sample1 = State()
sample2 = State()
sample3 = State()

After you should link your states class with appropriate handlers:
async def start(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext)

To control which handlers can work, you can extend code:
@dp.message_handler(**StateFilter(None)**,commands=['start'])

To clear states, just use:
await state.clear()

If you have more questions about FSM, let me know. You can find some info in aiogram documentation.
